# How to make list of sprites from grid template list

Tags: list, grid, pygame, sprite, maze

I need create class with list of sprites which are characterise number 1 in grid list. But I need split window to len(grid), len(grid[0]) how Im doing in WallTile class. But I need to fill window with tiles on that place where is number 1 in grid. It will be a maze of tiles. I want to use sprite because I need use collision detection with tile wall.

```
width, height = 700, 700  #window size

grid = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]]



class WallTile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super(WallTile, self).__init__()
        self.TILE_W = width / len(grid)     # spliting window by len(grid) and set size of one tile
        self.TILE_H = height / len(grid[0])
        self.tiles_x = width / self.TILE_W    # size of all tiles
        self.tiles_y = height / self.TILE_H
        self.imageMaster = pygame.image.load("images/wallBig.png")
        self.image = self.imageMaster
        self.pozX = 0.0
        self.pozY = 0.0
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.imageMaster, (self.TILE_W, self.TILE_H))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (self.pozX, self.pozY)



        # here I need fill some sprite list with tiles with different coordinates.
            # I want to put tile on place where is number 1 in grid. But put it to screen.

        for y in range(self.tiles_y):
            for x in range(self.tiles_x):
                for i in range(len(grid[0])):
                    for j in range(len(grid)):
                        if grid[i][j] is 1:
                                # I need make new tile and put it to sprite list

                                self.pozX, self.pozY = (x * self.TILE_W), (y * self.TILE_H)

                                #
                                #--- here I dont know what to do...
                                #

class MainClass:
    def Main(self):

            # here is how Im drawing sprites on screen.

            screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
            screen.fill((grey))


            wallTile = WallTile()
            spriteGroup_1 = pygame.sprite.Group(wallTile)

            background = pygame.Surface(obrazovka.get_size())
            background.fill((grey))
            background.set_colorkey((60,0,0))

            running = True
            while running:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == QUIT or \
                        event.type == KEYDOWN and (event.key in [K_ESCAPE, K_q]):  
                            running = False


                        spriteGroup_1.clear(screen, background)
                        spriteGroup_1.update()
                        updateScreen = spriteGroup_1.draw(screen)

                        pygame.display.update(updateScreen)
                        pygame.display.flip()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    mainWin = MainClass()
    sys.exit((mainWin.Main()))
```

Really thanks for advices.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding exactly what the question is.  Why are you trying to maintain a list of sprites within the WallTile class, which is a sprite itself?

Comment: I dont know how to create more tiles like 1. Because in grid list there are more numbers 1. So I know how to create 1 sprite tile. I dont know how to create that much tiles, how many are numbers 1 in grid list. Is there some iterable sprite with some index where I can put more tiles and choose which get unique coordinates. So question is how to create in these class more tiles or that many tiles how many grid has numbers 1.

Comment: To begin with, your WallTile class is extending Sprite, so I don't see why you would want to keep a list of tiles within a WallTile object.  It makes more sense to have a list of Sprites outside of the scope of WallTile, with an initialization loop that looks at your grid and creates Sprites for each element of the grid with a value of 1.

Comment: But how to create it? I was try many things but not succesfully. How to create many tiles same class? I was trying create sprite list but its said me than sprite hasnt index for iterate.When I try add sprite with .add() how can I choose right one tile of many tiles there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would first redefine your WallTile class to only represent one tile.  The WallTile's constructor now accepts a size and location argument, which represent its size and location on the screen.

```
class WallTile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, size, location):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.size = size
        self.location = location
        self.image = pygame.image.load("images/wallBig.png")
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.image, size)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
```

Then, outside of the code for the WallTile class, you can inspect the grid for '1's and create a new tile whenever you find one.  You can look at the indices of that element on the grid, and multiply those values by the size of each tile to determine the location on the screen for that tile.  Then you can take that list of tiles and create a Sprite Group with them.

```
tile_size = (20, 20)
tiles = list()
for y in range(len(grid)):
    for x in range(len(grid[y])):
        if grid[x][y] == 1:            
            new_tile = WallTile(tile_size, (x * tile_size[0], y * tile_size[1]))
            tiles.append(new_tile)

tile_group = pygame.sprite.Group(tiles)
```

If you want to pull a specific tile from the group, and you don't already have a reference to that tile, you can loop over the group and look for a certain location

```
search_location = (40, 80)
for tile in tile_group:
    if tile.location = search_location:
        # we've found that tile, now do something with it
```